# Inequality in an unflattened triangle

Tags: geometry, analysis, triangles

Let a, b and c be the sides of an unflattened triangle, I want to prove that

$$\frac{a}{-a+b+c} + \frac{b}{a-b+c} + \frac{c}{a+b-c} ≥ 3$$

(we could take $x=-a+b+c$, ...)

The further I could get was having to prove that

$$ayz+xbz+xyc ≥ 3xyz$$

Which is something I am, so far, unable to prove...
Please help me to solve this I'm so frustrated of not being able to see it.

Comment: Did you try taking the LCD of the denominators of the original fraction? I think it would help you.

Comment: How am I supposed to find it with such unknowns ? Can't see it...

Comment: Actually I think it could but I'm still unable to see where does the 3 come from, using the said AM GM, I'm getting $\frac{\sqrt{yz}}{x} + \frac{\sqrt{xz}}{y} + \frac{\sqrt{xy}}{z}$, how come is that greater or equal to 3 ?